# Merge multiple dataframe rows into 1 column

Tags: python

When I collect time data, the day and time are on different rows. I like to combine the day and time to form a datetime column with both date and time.

This is a sample of the data I get

```
sampletest = pd.DataFrame(columns=['daytime','datetime'])

sampletest = sampletest.append({'daytime':'Sunday, January 1'}, ignore_index=True)
sampletest = sampletest.append({'daytime':'01:00'}, ignore_index=True)
sampletest = sampletest.append({'daytime':'13:00'}, ignore_index=True)
sampletest = sampletest.append({'daytime':'17:30'}, ignore_index=True)
sampletest = sampletest.append({'daytime':'19:00'}, ignore_index=True)
sampletest = sampletest.append({'daytime':'Monday, January 2'}, ignore_index=True)
sampletest = sampletest.append({'daytime':'08:00'}, ignore_index=True)
sampletest = sampletest.append({'daytime':'09:00'}, ignore_index=True)
sampletest = sampletest.append({'daytime':'10:30'}, ignore_index=True)
sampletest = sampletest.append({'daytime':'11:30'}, ignore_index=True)
```

This is a sample of what the end result should look like.

```
ConvertTime = pd.DataFrame(columns=['daytime','datetime'])
ConvertTime = ConvertTime.append({'daytime':'Sunday, January 1','datetime': np.NaN}, ignore_index=True)
ConvertTime = ConvertTime.append({'daytime':'01:00','datetime': '2023-01-01 01:00:00'}, ignore_index=True)
ConvertTime = ConvertTime.append({'daytime':'13:00','datetime': '2023-01-01 13:00:00'}, ignore_index=True)
ConvertTime = ConvertTime.append({'daytime':'17:30','datetime': '2023-01-01 17:30:00'}, ignore_index=True)
ConvertTime = ConvertTime.append({'daytime':'19:00','datetime': '2023-01-01 19:00:00'}, ignore_index=True)
ConvertTime = ConvertTime.append({'daytime':'Monday, January 2','datetime': np.NaN}, ignore_index=True)
ConvertTime = ConvertTime.append({'daytime':'08:00','datetime': '2023-01-02 08:00:00'}, ignore_index=True)
ConvertTime = ConvertTime.append({'daytime':'09:00','datetime': '2023-01-02 09:00:00'}, ignore_index=True)
ConvertTime = ConvertTime.append({'daytime':'10:30','datetime': '2023-01-02 10:00:00'}, ignore_index=True)
ConvertTime = ConvertTime.append({'daytime':'11:30','datetime': '2023-01-02 11:00:00'}, ignore_index=True)
```

How should I script this merger? Also, the data does not have year so, we will assume all days are 2023.

Comment: Is the sample data coming from a csv or established dataframe? The sample above will continue to overwrite "sampletest" and doesn't look like a traditional dataset to parse through.

Comment: It a dataframe I created when I scraped this site. "https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```py
m = sampletest['daytime'].str.match('\d{2}:\d{2}')
sampletest['datetime'] = (
    pd.to_datetime((sampletest['daytime'] + ' 2023').where(~m))
    .ffill()
    .add(pd.to_timedelta((sampletest['daytime'] + ':00').where(m)))
    .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # In case you want strings
)
```

Or, a bit simpler:

```py
m = sampletest['daytime'].str.match('\d{2}:\d{2}')
sampletest['datetime'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(
        (sampletest['daytime'] + ' 2023 ').where(~m).ffill()
        + sampletest['daytime'].where(m)
    )
    .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # In case you want strings
)
```

Result for the sample:

```
             daytime             datetime
0  Sunday, January 1                  NaN
1              01:00  2023-01-01 01:00:00
2              13:00  2023-01-01 13:00:00
3              17:30  2023-01-01 17:30:00
4              19:00  2023-01-01 19:00:00
5  Monday, January 2                  NaN
6              08:00  2023-01-02 08:00:00
7              09:00  2023-01-02 09:00:00
8              10:30  2023-01-02 10:30:00
9              11:30  2023-01-02 11:30:00
```

PS: Don't use `.append`. It is depreciated and doesn't work anymore with the current Pandas version.

Answer (score 0):

## Merge date and time rows into a single column

```
df['datetime'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row['date'] + ' ' + row['time']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: it is for example. you can modify your code

Comment: You don't seem understand the question?

Comment: Sometimes the title and descriptions are unrelated that's why I was getting confused.